# Sysprep copying user account detail - Need to avoid User Account

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, sysprep, imagex

I have to Create WIM for Installation like OEM does. I have created reference image with third party apps and driver. 
I have used SYSPREP tool present in Win 7 by selecting Enter System Out-of-Box-Experience(OOBE)->Genreralize and shutdown. When i copy and apply using Imagex tool . I am getting user account detail of reference Image which i don't required. Is there any option to do it. Or any other tool available to do the same

Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sysprep doesn't remove users account. When you start your customization, don't go through the Windows Welcome wizard to create a user. Instead enter Audit Mode by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> at the start of the wizard. The system will now reboot into Audit Mode and you are logged on as the built-in Administrator. You can now make the changes to the system and run sysprep when you are finished. Using this procedure you will not create a new user each time you modify a system. You can also delete the users you created earlier from Audit Mode.

[**Building a Standard Image of Windows 7: Step-by-Step Guide**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523217%28WS.10%29.aspx)